# TinyTds - Adaptive server is unavailable or does not exist

Tags: sql-server, ruby, linux, freetds, tiny-tds

**Machine 1:**

```
>tsql -C
Compile-time settings (established with the "configure" script)
                            Version: freetds v0.91.90
             freetds.conf directory: /etc
     MS db-lib source compatibility: no
        Sybase binary compatibility: no
                      Thread safety: yes
                      iconv library: yes
                        TDS version: 4.2
                              iODBC: no
                           unixodbc: yes
              SSPI "trusted" logins: no
                           Kerberos: no
```

I have the freeTDS installed and able to make a connection to the mssql,

```
> TDSVER=4.2 tsql -S xx.xx.xxx.xxx -U xxxx -P xxxx -p 1433
locale is "en_US.UTF-8"
locale charset is "UTF-8"
using default charset "UTF-8"
1>
```

So, when i try connecting from TinyTds, it is throwing the below error,

```
Adaptive server is unavailable or does not exist
```

**Machine 2:**

The configuration is same as in the machine 1, and from this machine, it is connecting to the mssql with TinyTds

```
>tsql -C
    Compile-time settings (established with the "configure" script)
                                Version: freetds v0.91.90
                 freetds.conf directory: /etc
         MS db-lib source compatibility: no
            Sybase binary compatibility: no
                          Thread safety: yes
                          iconv library: yes
                            TDS version: 4.2
                                  iODBC: no
                               unixodbc: yes
                  SSPI "trusted" logins: no
                               Kerberos: no
```

I have the freeTDS installed and able to make a connection to the mssql,

```
> TDSVER=4.2 tsql -S xx.xx.xxx.xxx -U xxxx -P xxxx -p 1433
locale is "en_US.UTF-8"
locale charset is "UTF-8"
using default charset "UTF-8"
1>

Able to connect to the server using TinyTds
```

I am not sure why this is happening or where to check and i don't think it is a firewall issue as i am able to connect from the terminal, also i have verified its credentials etc., all are same  except that the connection is unsuccessful. Any help much appreciated!

Note: The scenario is,

I am running a test through jenkins, where it is running the ruby process using the slave 'machine1', where it is not able to connect to the sqlserver(having freetds configured) throwing Adaptive server unavailable or does not exist error.

when i modify the slave to 'machine2', it is establishing the connection, despite having the same freetds configuration as machine1

Comment: Does each machine have it's own SQL Server running or are both machines connecting to SQL Server elsewhere?

Comment: I was able to fix it changing :dataserver to :host

Answer (score 2):

My problem was resolved after I enabled port 1433 on all connections

[image]