# Bitnami Redmine Unable to connect: Adaptive Server

Tags: sql-server, windows, redmine, bitnami

I am trying to install **Bitnami Redmine 4.1.1-8** on a MS SQL 2107 server from a Windows 10 Pro computer.
This is a clean computer with no other versions of Redmine. Unfortunately, every time I try to execute the command bundle `exec thin -e production start` I get this error:

```
C:\Bitnami\redmine-4.1.1-8\apps\redmine\htdocs> bundle exec thin -e production start
Using rack adapter
Traceback (most recent call last):
86: from C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/bin/thin:23:in <main>'
85: from C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/bin/thin:23:inload'
84: from C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/thin-1.7.2-x64-mingw32/bin/thin:6:in <top (required)>'
83: from C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/thin-1.7.2-x64-mingw32/lib/thin/runner.rb:159:inrun!'
82: from C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/thin-1.7.2-x64-mingw32/lib/thin/runner.rb:203:in run_command'
81: from C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/thin-1.7.2-x64-mingw32/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:74:instart'
80: from C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/thin-1.7.2-x64-mingw32/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:170:in load_adapter'
79: from C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/thin-1.7.2-x64-mingw32/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:42:infor'
78: from C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/thin-1.7.2-x64-mingw32/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:33:in load'
77: from C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/thin-1.7.2-x64-mingw32/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:33:ineval'
76: from C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/apps/redmine/htdocs/config.ru:1:in <main>'
75: from C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/apps/redmine/htdocs/config.ru:1:innew'
74: from C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:125:in initialize'
73: from C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:125:ininstance_eval'
72: from C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/apps/redmine/htdocs/config.ru:3:in block in <main>'
71: from C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/apps/redmine/htdocs/config.ru:3:inrequire'
70: from C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/apps/redmine/htdocs/config/environment.rb:16:in <top (required)>'
69: from C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.2/lib/rails/application.rb:361:ininitialize!'
68: from C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in run_initializers'
67: from C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/ruby/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:205:intsort_each'
66: from C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/ruby/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:226:in tsort_each'
65: from C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/ruby/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:ineach_strongly_connected_component'
64: from C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/ruby/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in call'
63: from C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/ruby/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:ineach'
62: from C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/ruby/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:349:in block in each_strongly_connected_component'
61: from C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/ruby/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:431:ineach_strongly_connected_component_from'
60: from C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/ruby/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:350:in block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
59: from C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/ruby/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:228:inblock in tsort_each'
58: from C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in block in run_initializers'
57: from C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:inrun'
56: from C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in instance_exec'
55: from C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.2/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:69:inblock in '
54: from C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.2/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:69:in each'
53: from C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:356:ineager_load!'
52: from C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:475:in eager_load!'
51: from C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:475:ineach'
50: from C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:477:in block in eager_load!'
49: from C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:477:ineach'
48: from C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:478:in block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
47: from C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:246:inrequire_dependency'
46: from C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:334:in depend_on'
45: from C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:356:inrequire_or_load'
44: from C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:37:in load_interlock'
43: from C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.2/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:13:inloading'
42: from C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.2/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:151:in exclusive'
41: from C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.2/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:14:inblock in loading'
40: from C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:37:in block in load_interlock'
39: from C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:378:inblock in require_or_load'
38: from C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in require'
37: from C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:inload_dependency'
36: from C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in block in require'
35: from C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:inrequire'
34: from C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/apps/redmine/htdocs/app/models/issue_query.rb:20:in <top (required)>'
33: from C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/apps/redmine/htdocs/app/models/issue_query.rb:36:in'
32: from C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/apps/redmine/htdocs/app/models/issue_query.rb:36:in new'
31: from C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/apps/redmine/htdocs/app/models/query.rb:31:ininitialize'
30: from C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/apps/redmine/htdocs/app/models/query.rb:91:in groupable'
29: from C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/apps/redmine/htdocs/app/models/user.rb:816:incurrent'
28: from C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/apps/redmine/htdocs/app/models/user.rb:822:in anonymous'
27: from C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.2/lib/active_record/scoping/default.rb:34:inunscoped'
26: from C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.2/lib/active_record/core.rb:287:in relation'
25: from C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.2/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:84:infinder_needs_type_condition?'
24: from C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.2/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:78:in descends_from_active_record?'
23: from C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.2/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:336:incolumns_hash'
22: from C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.2/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:456:in load_schema'
21: from C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/ruby/lib/ruby/2.5.0/monitor.rb:235:inmon_synchronize'
20: from C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.2/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:459:in block in load_schema'
19: from C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.2/lib/active_record/attribute_decorators.rb:51:inload_schema!'
18: from C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.2/lib/active_record/attributes.rb:234:in load_schema!'
17: from C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.2/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:466:inload_schema!'
16: from C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.2/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:90:in connection'
15: from C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.2/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:118:inretrieve_connection'
14: from C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:1033:in retrieve_connection'
13: from C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:382:inconnection'
12: from C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:538:in checkout'
11: from C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:814:inacquire_connection'
10: from C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:853:in try_to_checkout_new_connection'
9: from C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:874:incheckout_new_connection'
8: from C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:830:in new_connection'
7: from C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-5.2.1/lib/active_record/sqlserver_base.rb:13:insqlserver_connection'
6: from C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-5.2.1/lib/active_record/sqlserver_base.rb:13:in new'
5: from C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-5.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver_adapter.rb:64:ininitialize'
4: from C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-5.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver_adapter.rb:365:in connect'
3: from C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-5.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver_adapter.rb:379:indblib_connect'
2: from C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-5.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver_adapter.rb:379:in new'
1: from C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/tiny_tds-2.1.3-x64-mingw32/lib/tiny_tds/client.rb:60:ininitialize'
C:/Bitnami/redmine-4.1.1-8/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/tiny_tds-2.1.3-x64-mingw32/lib/tiny_tds/client.rb:60:in `connect': Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist (127.0.0.1) (TinyTds::Error)
```

Here's my full database/yml file:

```
production:
adapter: sqlserver
host: 127.0.0.1
port: 1433
database: DATABESE
username: user
password: "passwordpassword"
encoding: utf8
```

I am trying to install the program on a production MS SQL server of our company so that we can keep track of the employees activities, and I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: See my answer here for similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40883148/tinytds-adaptive-server-is-unavailable-or-does-not-exist

Answer (score 1):

Quite by accident, I managed to solve this problem myself.

1. It is necessary to specify the DNS server name, and not its IP, as I did.
2. After making all the changes to the adapter and connecting to the SQL server, you must run the procedure `bundle update`
3. After this shut dawn all server connections from Bitnami Stack Manager Tool
4. Run `bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production`
5. Re-start all server connections from Bitnami Stack Manager Tool

And that's all about it.